# Create thumbnails tile for time range of video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to create, let's say, 12 thumbnails from video, but skip 10 percent in the beginning and in the ending. I found [this](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20take%20multiple%20screenshots%20to%20an%20image%20%28tile,%20mosaic%29) thing, but it just takes every 1000th frame. In my case this range will be variable and it will be better if it will be in seconds. Can't figure out how to do this with ffmpeg, don't work with it much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -ss $skip_time -i $input_path -vframes 1 -vf select=isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,$screenshot_time), scale=iw*min($width/iw\,$height/ih):ih*min($width/iw\,$height/ih),pad=($width):($height):($width-iw)/2):($height-ih)/2),tile=3x4 -vcodec mjpeg $output_filename
```

`$skip_time` - time to skip from the beginning
`$screenshot_time` - time interval for screenshots to be taken

These values should be precalculated, I used `ffprobe` to get video duration.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this exact same problem so I'll share my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

thumb=160:90
tiles=4x3

for filename; do
  duration=$(ffprobe \
    -hide_banner \
    -select_streams v \
    -show_entries stream=duration \
    -of csv \
    "$filename" \
    | cut -d, -f2)
  interval=$(bc -e "scale=6;$duration/(${tiles/x/*}+1)")

  select_filter="if(isnan(prev_selected_t),floor(t/$interval),floor(t/$interval)-floor(prev_selected_t/$interval))"
  ffmpeg -i "$filename" \
    -hide_banner \
    -vframes 1 \
    -vf select="${select_filter//,/\,},scale=$thumb,tile=$tiles" \
    -update 1 \
    -y "${filename%.*}.png"
done
```

I've also tried with the `-r` option but found it less accurate.